# Guidewire Exception handling in UI

Tags: user-interface, exception, guidewire

when internal Guidewire code throws an exception you get a nicely formatted error message box. However, when custom code throws an exception you are directed to the error page (with the red stack trace text & back to application button). Is there anything in the Guidewire framework to make proper UI handling of errors nicer?

such as: < TextBox value="user.someMethod()"/>

```
//someMethod code...
try{
    return user.someOtherCode()
}catch(e : Exception){
    //TODO: gracefully display erorr mesage on page
    //e.g.   showErrorMessage()
    return null
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a simpler way to do this,

The below piece of code can be written in helper class or any Enhancement or even in PCF code tab, this will return a nice formatted error message.

**gw.api.util.LocationUtil.addRequestScopedErrorMessage("Your error message")**

Comment: Can It block the binding? Or If we add an error message in this addRequestScopedError method it will just throw the error message but will allow to bind.

Answer (score 0):

After some searching through Guidewire OOTB code UserDisplayableExceptions are what you need - answering myself in case someone else has this thought.

```
function goToPolicy(bulkDocumentDownload : BulkDocDownload_Avi) {
  try {
    throw new IndexOutOfBoundsException("Ops! some index out of bounds exception was thrown")
  } catch (e : Exception) {
    throw new com.guidewire.pl.web.controller.UserDisplayableException(e.Message)
  }
}
```

Comment: Please find my comment below.